# Iterate over rows and columns in csv/xlsx file python 3

Tags: python, excel, csv, pandas

I am new to Stack Overflow and have a problem which I can not solve. 
I have a csv file or excel (basically a table) and want to do the following in Python 3:

```
Column Header,"r269_d","r295_A","r295_R","r299_A","r325_D","r326_A"

id1,"0.0","2.29","0.0","1.3","0.0","188.4"

id2,"0.0","1.0","0.0","0.6","0.0","0.0"
```

For this csv file I want to:

1. Go in first row (id1)
2. Check column 1 (r269_d)

   2.1 If value of col1 = 0 write 0 to new result_string

   2.2 If value of col1 != 0 write 1 to new result_string
3. Check column 2 (r295_A)

   3.1 If value of col2 = 0 write 0 to the same result_string as mentioned in 2.1

   3.2 If value of col2 != 0 write 1 to the same result_string as mentioned in 2.1
4. Do that for all columns
5. Go to next row and do the same.

In the end I want to have something looking like this:

```
Column Header,"r269_d","r295_A","r295_R","r299_A","r325_D","r326_A", "result_string"

id1,"0.0","2.29","0.0","1.3","0.0","188.4","010101"

id2,"0.0","1.0","0.0","0.6","0.0","0.0","010100"
```

Comment: Google "python csv" and see how far you can get.

Comment: Check the python csv module for csv. For xlsx you can use xlsxwriter.

Comment: please check out [pyexcel](https://github.com/pyexcel/pyexcel/tree/master/examples/basics)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas solution:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv(r'/path/to/file.csv')

df['result_string'] = (df.filter(regex='r\d+')
                         .ne(0).astype(np.int8).astype(str)
                         .apply(''.join, axis=1))

df.to_csv(r'/path/to/result.csv', index=False)
```

Source CSV file:

```
col,r269_d,r295_A,r295_R,r299_A,r325_D,r326_A
id1,0.0,2.29,0.0,1.3,0.0,188.4
id2,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.6,0.0,0.0
```

Parsed DF:

```
In [169]: df
Out[169]:
   col  r269_d  r295_A  r295_R  r299_A  r325_D  r326_A
0  id1     0.0    2.29     0.0     1.3     0.0   188.4
1  id2     0.0    1.00     0.0     0.6     0.0     0.0
```

Result:

```
In [170]: df['result_string'] = (df.filter(regex='r\d+')
     ...:                          .ne(0).astype(np.int8).astype(str)
     ...:                          .apply(''.join, axis=1))
     ...:

In [171]: df
Out[171]:
   col  r269_d  r295_A  r295_R  r299_A  r325_D  r326_A result_string
0  id1     0.0    2.29     0.0     1.3     0.0   188.4        010101
1  id2     0.0    1.00     0.0     0.6     0.0     0.0        010100

In [172]: df.to_csv(r'c:/temp/result.csv', index=False)
```

Resulting CSV:

```
col,r269_d,r295_A,r295_R,r299_A,r325_D,r326_A,result_string
id1,0.0,2.29,0.0,1.3,0.0,188.4,010101
id2,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.6,0.0,0.0,010100
```